Showing an asymptotic $\sim$ relation for complicated terms

Let

$f(x) = x + \frac{x^3}{3}$,
$a(z) := x^3+x$,
$b(z) := 3x^3+x$,
$\delta(x) = \frac{1}{x^{4/3}}$.

Is it true that
$$f(xe^{i\delta}) \sim f(x) \exp\biggl(a(x)i\delta - b(x) \frac{\delta^2}{2} \biggr) \quad \text{ for } x \rightarrow \infty \quad ?$$

By the definition of the $\sim$ relation we need to show that for $x \rightarrow \infty$ holds
\begin{align}
\frac{f(xe^{i\delta})}{f(x) \exp\biggl(a(x)i\delta - b(x) \frac{\delta^2}{2} \biggr) } = \frac{xe^{i\delta(x)} + \frac{x^3}{3}e^{i3\delta(x)}}{\biggl(x+\frac{x^3}{3}\biggr) \exp\biggl( (x^3+x)i\delta(x) - (3x^3+x) \frac{\delta^2(x)}{2} \biggr) }\rightarrow 1
\end{align}
I can see that $b(x)\delta^2(x) \rightarrow \infty$, but I do not know how to proceed further. Could you please help me?

is $i$ the imaginary unit or a real constant?

It is the imaginary unit.
